# Qooxdoo TreeVirtual ContextMenu

Tags: qooxdoo

How can I implement a ContextMenu on a column in TreeeVirtual in Qooxdoo?
I found an example for table:
table.setContextMenuHandler(2, this._contextMenuHandlerNull);
but it does not work in treevirtual case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that you include the Context menu mixin in the table class:

```
qx.Class.include(qx.ui.table.Table, qx.ui.table.MTableContextMenu);
```

As the tree virtual extend the table, the context menu will be available after you have included the mixin. Take a look at the following sample to see it running:

http://tinyurl.com/7nxm3uc